# dmChannel is not working and is returning null

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a problem. The bot doesn't want to get `dmChannel` from the author object in a message. The dmChannel is always `null`. This is my code:

```
    if (command === "suggest") {
  message.channel.send("**Please, revise the DM that I sent you.**");
  let msg = message.author.send("Please, state a valid suggestion. Max time: 3 mins. If you want to cancel, say `cancel`.");
  let filter = m => m.content.includes('');
  msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 180000, errors: ['time'] })
  .then(collected => {
    if (collected.content.toLowerCase() === "cancel") {return;}
    client.channels.cache.get('790403704171659274').send(new MessageEmbed().setTitle("New Suggestion!").setColor("c0ed8c").setDescription(package.description).setFooter("Made by " + message.author.toString(), client.user.avatarURL()).setTimestamp().addField("Suggestion", collected.content));
  })
  .catch(collected => {
    if(collected.size === 0) {message.author.send("Prompt cancelled."); return;}
    message.author.send("Thanks for making your suggestions! They are all apreciated.")
  });
}
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Is it telling you the line where the error is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an issue because you're not awaiting a couple of things, I do the exact same thing and it works fine.

Such as `msg`, try `let msg = await message.author.send('your message')`

and the `msg.channel.awaitMessages()` try `await msg.channel.awaitMessage`

I could be wrong but as I said before, I do the exact same thing in a DM channel and it works fine.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for helping me. It's the same. I got the same result: `null`. I tried it out too later on. Any ideas?